# Expectation of a cubic transformation of a Bernoulli random variable

Tags: self-study, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

I was asked the following question: $X$ is a random variable which follows a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$ and take $Y=a+bX$. Compute $\mathbb{E}(Y^3)$.

Comment: That's the thing I don't even know where to start. I am not aksing for the fully developed solution. But if someone could be knd enough to at least tell me how I can start solving this....

Comment: Can you try to compute $\mathbb{E}[X]$, $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$, $\mathbb{E}[X^3]$? Then you are almost done.

Comment: E[X] = p right ? then  E[X^2] = p^2 and so on

Comment: Ok so  E[X]= p,  E[X^2] = p,  E[X^3] = p

Comment: You are one line away from the answer: what is $Y^3$?

Comment: Not so sure about this one. Math is not my strong suit.Y^3 = (a+bX)^3

Comment: Multiplication distributes over addition - expand out the brackets.

Answer (score 4):

When it comes to computing expectations of discrete variables with a small number of possible values, I have often found it instructive to make a table of values and probabilities.  For instance, a table for the Bernoulli$(p)$ variable $X$ might look like

$$\begin{array}{r | c c | r}
  & X & \text{Probability} &X \times \text{Probability}\\
\hline
  & 0 & 1-p & 0 \\
  & 1 & p & p \\
 \hline \text{Total} & & 1 & \mathbb{E}[X]=p
\end{array}$$

The full information about the variable is contained in the two columns headed "$X$" (the values of $X$) and "Probability" (the chances of each value).  The rightmost column shows the calculation of the expectation: one finds the products of the values and the probabilities, then adds them up.

From this table you can easily compute a table for the random variables $Y = a+bX$ and $Y^3$.

$$\begin{array}{r | c c r r | r}
  & X & \text{Probability} & Y & Y^3 & Y^3 \times \text{Probability}\\
\hline
  & 0 & 1-p & a + b\times 0 = a & a^3 &? \\
  & 1 & p & a + b\times 1 = a + b & (a+b)^3 & ? \\
 \hline \text{Total} & & 1 & & & \mathbb{E}[Y^3]=?
\end{array}$$

I have left it to the interested reader to compute the missing values.

Comment: Magisterial! Happy fall, Professor!

Comment: Thank you, @Antoni.  If you think of the rows of this table as [tickets](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/96000/919), then the table describes an entire box of tickets and their proportions in the box.  It's an effective metaphor.